# How to save JSpinner values in variables as a permanent unchangeable value?

Tags: java

I have a JSpinner Number Model as in the following Picture:

[image: JSpinner]

I saved the value shown in the Width for example in a Double variable as

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
    doublewidth =(Double) spinnerwidth.getModel().getValue();
}
```

Now the value of JSpinner Width saved to doublewidth = 60, but if i change Width again to 300 as an example now doublewidth = 300  but I dont want that to happen.

I want doublewidth to save the value of 60 no matter what happens to JSpinner.

Can you help me please?

Comment: you can disable you jspinner like that you can't edit it any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize doubleWidth set it to

```
doubleWidth = -1
```

then inside your stateChanged method only adjust it if it is still equal to -1.

```
if (doubleWith == -1){
    doublewidth =(Double) spinnerwidthto.getModel().getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply@JynXXedRabbitFoot . could you please tell me if i want that JSpinner of (Width) with value saved in double doublewidth =60 , to be changed again with a new value like 70 , how can i save the new value of the same jspinner of width without deleting the old value . because i want to do some calculation later with the variables . thanks

Comment: @Fashtaki If this answered the original question you asked please accept it as such. As for the new question, how many times do you need to save new values? How would the user know that they were adding new information and not just adjusting the original input? Would it make more sense to have 2 width spinners? While you could certainly  add an else to the if == -1 that sets a second variable, it may be worth rethinking your approach.

Comment: in the pic above i have Track Jspinner . i want for  Track =1 to chosse some parameters of Length, heigt and width , all the values then saved in a variables , then for Track = 2 i want to chosse another values of Length, heigt and width and save them in variables. At the end i want to take the both Track values and make some Calculation with its variable and save it in an XML file . so i need like ex iwant this to happend  ( doublewidth 1 = 60 , doublewidth 2= 70) but as you know if i change jspiner to 70  doublewidth 1 will equal = 70

Comment: As for the tracks, if you only allow 2 tracks you could store the values in an    int array `new int[2][3]` initially it will be all zeros, and set the appropriate value on stateChanged if it is still zero in the array.